# Pyspark or Pandas - compare col1 of DF1 and col2 of DF2 and remove duplicate words in col1 based on col2

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I want to remove the words present in the list of col2 of DF2 from col1 of DF1.
DF2 has only one list.
DF1 has multiple lists and each list is in one row.

DF1
[image]

DF2
[image]

DF1 Output/Result
[image]

In the output/result, I want to keep the repeating words of DF1 for each row. I tried array_except(),it gives the desired output but also removes the duplicates within each row of DF1, like, instead of 2 D's only 1 D comes out in the result. Any other solution?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DF2 contains only one list, it probably does not need to be a dataframe, it can just be a list. Try this:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [['A', 'B', 'D', 'D'], ['A', 'G']]})
to_remove = ['A', 'B', 'E']
df1['col3'] = df1['col1'].apply(lambda list_: [val for val in list_ if val not in to_remove])
print(df1)

           col1    col3
0  [A, B, D, D]  [D, D]
1        [A, G]     [G]
```